# Querying JSON field in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with several fields (id, title, json_field). I want to select all rows from this table, but I want each parameter inside json_field to be a separate row in result. I guess I should use `json_array_elements`, but the problem is that I can't understand how to include it in my query.

Is there are solution? I expected it to work with with this query:

`select id, title, json_array_elements(json_field) from table_name`, but it doesn't.

I also tried to pass subquery result as an argument, not succeeded as well.

I read through the docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) but I can't find anything helpful.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Show the json values

Comment: Do you get an error? or how exactly it does not work?

Comment: when you ask questions please provide table definitions, sample data and expected results. otherwise it is too much guesswork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to apply `json_array_elements()` function to VARCHAR and TEXT fields and it does not work:

> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.

However, it seems to work fine with JSON type. See SqlFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2977f/3

So all you need to do is to cast your field to JSON data type:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0fa19/1

Comment: Thank you! That was a problem. I use Doctrine to communicate with database, and the field type was text, not json. I've just changed it to json and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me

```
select 1, 2, json_array_elements('[1,true, [2,false]]');
 ?column? | ?column? | json_array_elements 
----------+----------+---------------------
        1 |        2 | 1
        1 |        2 | true
        1 |        2 | [2,false]
```

Also works with a table

```
select id, title, json_array_elements(j) as j
from (values
    (1, 'the title', '[1,true, [2,false]]'::json)
) s(id, title, j);
 id |   title   |     j     
----+-----------+-----------
  1 | the title | 1
  1 | the title | true
  1 | the title | [2,false]
```

Comment: how about the real table?

Comment: @Bulat I don't see a real table in the question. Do  you?

Comment: I do: "I have a table with several fields (id, title, json_field)."

Comment: @Bulat He has. I don't. The best I can do it to create one myself as I did on my real answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60394/discussion-between-bulat-and-clodoaldo-neto).